# Ruby bindings to GDAL

Tags: gdal, ruby

I'm looking for a guide on how to get up and running with ruby and gdal on Mac. I've seen some examples on how to use gdal in ruby but never found any tutorials on where to download and install it.

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it, it looks like you have to complie the GDAL libs your self with the --with-ruby switch in order to get the ruby bindings. Although I have never done this myself so dragons maybe ahead; be warned.

I can't seem to find pre built GDAL with ruby bindings.  .

Edit:  I did find this for Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/libgdal-ruby1.8

Answer (score 0):

Here some Ruby [gem](https://github.com/zhm/gdal-ruby) but not working on version 2.0+ 
Works fine on Mac.

As for me, for now, there are no production ready solutions for Ruby.
I would recommend trying to use GDAL bindings for Python. Python is very similar to Ruby.